# Wave Function Question

Tags: functions

For part a) the value of a=60° and k=2, therefore the answer is 2sin(x+60)°.

I am struggling in part b) on how to find an answer, the answer is := min. of 2 @ x=30°.
Can someone help on how to solve part b).
[image]

Comment: i am unsure, can someone help.

Comment: I could solve part a) easily using the the wave function technique, but I really need help with part b),

Comment: factorise the expression to find value of x

Comment: i really have no clue for this question...

Comment: just please give a clear answer...

Comment: It has no growth at the minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: To minimize $f$ you want to maximize the denominator.  $\sin \theta$ is maximized at $\theta = 90$.